# Strongloop Loopback remote hooks not triggered with supertest?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, supertest

We are testing our loopback API code using spec.js files like this:

Require libs:

```
var app     = rewire('../..');
var request = require('supertest');
var assert  = require('chai').assert;
```

json helper method to standardize headers and content type:

```
function json(verb, url) {
  return request(app)[verb](url)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
}
```

A test of a custom remote method that requires auth:

```
describe("Order remote methods", function() {

  var accessTokenId, userId;

    // authenticate before each test and save token
    before(function(done) {
      json('post', '/api/People/login')
      .send({ email: 'user@email.com', password: 'password' })
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {

        accessTokenId = res.body.id;
        userId = res.body.userId;

        assert(res.body.id);
        assert(res.body.userId);

        done();
      });
  });

  it("should fetch user orders", function(done) {
    json('get', '/api/Orders/specialOrders')
      .set('Authorization', accessTokenId)
      .send({id: userId})
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        var orders = res.body.orders;
        assert(Array.isArray(orders), "Orders should be an array");
        // more asserts for explicit data values
        done();
      });
  });

});
```

`/api/Orders/specialOrders` is a custom remote method that does a custom query on the Order model, which works as expected. But when I add a `beforeRemote` hook for this model, ***it does not get triggered by running the test.*** Is this expected or is my test setup not complete?

Remote hook:

```
Order.beforeRemote('specialOrders', function(ctx, unused, next) {

  console.log('[userOrders]');
  console.log('ctx req token: ', ctx.req.accessToken.userId);
  console.log('ctx args: ', ctx.req.params.id);

  // prevent remote method from being called
  // even without a next(), remote is executed!
  next(new Error('testing error'));

});
```

Running the same custom method via the Explorer UI, the `beforeRemote` hook is triggered as expected, and reports the custom error (or hangs when the `next()` is not present).

Is it possible to get supertest to trigger remote hooks in tests like this or am I missing some `app` setup in the spec file?

Comment: What is your server startup script for the test ?

Comment: Im using beforeRemote hooks and this is something that happens to me in a regular (non-test) run, i.e. even if the beforeRemote returns a next(error); the remote gets executed, however I still get the correct error code and message from the error object, so I'm guessing the remote hook is executed regardless of what beforeRemote does, except that in the end we do return the result object from the beforeRemote hook (i.e. the error)

Comment: What it's the `err` and `res.body` do you get in the test? I'm using supertest to call my loopback API and I have models with beforeRemote hooks and those are triggered properly.

Comment: I think I am facing a similar error as you are. Did you manage to find the error?

Comment: @Kaleidophon sorry, this was so long ago that we stopped testing this way. Now we're doing more unit tests and not worrying so much that the cals are being made via rest endpoints, but it still crops up from time to time.

Comment: @Overdrivr - what do you mean by starttup script? I was setting a rewire'd version of the app using require(../..) that pulls in server/server.js, but this was a long while ago so I'll have to revisit when I get a chance. But that gets to the heart of what I'm looking for how to do - guess I need a separate version of the app running instead of having it encapsulated in the tests themselves?